Group of people in the mountains, one of them is a killer
If I remember correctly the movie had a female protagonist, maybe the group was hiking or skiing or researching, something along those lines, someone gets killed, maybe even a couple of them (one by one?).
The movie must be from the 90s, maybe late 80s.
There was something about the moment the heroine realized who the murderer is, it's revealed with a flashback to where one of the group members tells her about a method to find out who the killer is, the member had it laid out on a note pad or piece of paper. 
I think in the end there are only two survivors.
It was like 10 years ago when I saw it the last time, can't tell much about the actors, but they were no heavyweight Hollywood actors, maybe the female protagonist. The setting was high mountains like, it had some production value to it. I can't remember much more, only that it delivered the suspense quite well with a scary undertone. That's what really stuck to me not so much the plot or cast, sorry. Hope it helps.

I'm pretty sure it was an american movie.

Welcome to Movies & TV!  What country was it set in? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors? Please try to provide some more detail, otherwise I'm afraid this question is likely to be put on hold.

Hey Paulie,thanks for the reply

It was like 10 years ago when I saw it the last time, can't tell much about the actors, but they were no heavyweight hollywood actors, maybe the female protagonist. The setting was high mountains like, it had some production value to it. I can't remember much more, only that it delievered the suspense quite well with a scary undertone. That's what really stuck to me not so much the plot or cast, sorry. Hope it helps.

Was it an Agatha Christie story?

Shoot to Kill (1988) seems to fit the bill. The basic premise is the same as you described. I have not seen this film in a while, I do not remember whether the notepad/piece of paper part is in there, but otherwise the movie matches your description.
You can watch it on Youtube here, albeit in crap quality:



Another link where you can watch it:



IMDb plot summary:

"Sidney Poitier returned to the big screen in this action-thriller,
  after a decade-long absence. When a cunning murderer vanishes into the
  rugged mountains of the Pacific Northwest, pursuing FBI agent Warren
  Stantin (Poitier) must exchange familiar city streets for unknown
  wilderness trails. Completely out of his element, Stantin is forced to
  enlist the aid of expert tracker Jonathan Knox (PLATOON'S Tom
  Berenger). The killer has infiltrated a guided hiking trip led by
  Knox's girlfriend Sarah (Kirstie Alley, at the height of her Cheers
  fame). Viewers don't know which of the hikers is the killer, and the
  tension lasts well into the movie."

You can read the Wikipedia plot description here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoot_to_Kill_(1988_film)

"Feeling that he has failed, Stantin becomes obsessed with finding
  Steve, and he chases Steve into the rugged forests of the state of
  Washington, where Steve joins up with a group of sportsmen who plan to
  trek into the wilderness on a fishing trip. Steve's plan is to kill
  them and force their guide, Sarah (Kirstie Alley), to lead him through
  the wilderness to the Canada–US border."


Interesting, the description fits really well indeed, but that wasn't the movie, the cast was younger in the other movie. Thanks for the reply.
